# ListView.Builder play/Pause buttom flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using a ListView.builder to create an audio list, I need to change the play button pause individually to an item when I select it, I have tried a bool but giving play or pause changes all the items in the list, someone can you help with that ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a **list of boolean** to save which button is selected, then pass the bool as a parameter to the audio widget, and use the bool to change the icon.

Also pass a **callback** function to change the bool list, because you have to change the list from the parent widget, so a callback function is needed.

```dart
 List<bool> audioSelectedList = List.generate(AudioList.length, (i) => false);

// This is a callback function that Audio will call when the button is clicked.
  selected(int index){
// set only one bool to be true
    setState(() {
      audioSelectedList=List.generate(AudioList.length, (i) => false);// set all to false
      audioSelectedList[index]=true;  // set the selected index to be true
    });
  }
```

ListView:

```dart
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: AudioList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Audio(
            selected: selected, // pass the callback function
            index: index, // use to call selected(index)
            isSelected: audioSelectedList[index], // only one bool is true in the list which is the selected index.
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Could you explain the code a little better to me, please

Comment: hey @sleepingkit, can you help me, in my case i am using from.Json like this and passing it to another widget.                                                                                                                                                   PostModel posts = PostModel.fromJson(post[index].data());                                                                           return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: UserPost(post: posts), // I use posts here
                );

Answer (score 5):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(isPressed
                      ? Icons.play_circle_filled
                      : Icons.pause_circle_filled),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isPressed = !isPressed;
                    });
                  }),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(isPressed
                      ? Icons.play_circle_filled
                      : Icons.pause_circle_filled),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isPressed = !isPressed;
                    });
                  }),
              PlayPause(
                isPressed: isPressed,
              ),
              PlayPause(),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlayPause extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayPause({
    Key key,
    this.isPressed = false,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final bool isPressed;

  @override
  _PlayPauseState createState() => _PlayPauseState();
}

class _PlayPauseState extends State<PlayPause> {
  bool _isPressed;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isPressed = widget.isPressed;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
            _isPressed ? Icons.play_circle_filled : Icons.pause_circle_filled),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _isPressed = !_isPressed;
          });
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use one bool for all of your audio, you can use collections to define a bool for everything in your audioList, and when you click, change the bool for the audio.