# How to update children of ExpansionTile widget when it is expanded in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have the following `ExpansionTile` widget, and i'm trying to update the children only when the widget is expanded , which means the widget has a Text child "null" by default but when i expanded it i want the child to be "updated" .
However when i print the value of child after i expand the widget it show "updated" but in the app it shows "null"

```
   return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) {
              String child = 'null';
                return ExpansionTile(
                     onExpansionChanged: (expanded) {
                         if (expanded) {
                         setState(() => child = "updated");
                        }
                    },
       children: [
            Text(child),
            ],
         );
      },
   );
```

Comment: make your String child, a class level variable..above @override Widget build()

Comment: @Reign , the issue is the ExpansionTile  is nested really deep inside a another state full widget so when i did what you just commented the bigger widget gets updated but not the  ExpansionTile, thanks

Comment: @Reign so the whole screen gets reloaded when i expand the widget , is there a way to make a child widget defined as a statfull widget with its own State ?

Comment: if thats the case, you should refractor that widget and only in that class Widget stateful it will rebuild. So it wont affect your main bigger widgets

Comment: refer in this example. it just almost same problem.I have my answer there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63496481/listview-builder-play-pause-buttom-flutter/63496800#63496800

Comment: @Reign that's awesome buddy really appreciate it

Comment: @Reign post your answer please so i mark it as a solution