# Flutter multiple action

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a like button, which works like toggle, the color will change to make it liked by tap action, and tap it again to dislike it. how can I achieve that?

Comment: have you tried anything? Please try first with your self. Have you checked existing questions on SO?

Comment: Look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/63496800/12789200

Comment: i make a function which parameter receive many action, but i think i dont do it effectively, so it dont works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple button like this:

```
IconButton(
   onPressed: () {
       setState(() {
           _isLiked = !_isLiked;
        });
       }
      },
   icon: Icon(Constants.crownIcon, 
       color: _isLiked
              ? Constants.orangeColor 
              : Constants.ligthGreyColor, 
     size: 15.0,
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ToggleButtons](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html)

```
ToggleButtons(
  children: <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
    Icon(Icons.call),
    Icon(Icons.cake),
  ],
  onPressed: (int index) {
    setState(() {
      isSelected[index] = !isSelected[index];
    });
  },
  isSelected: isSelected,
),
```

Comment: this should be the comment. or its better you also add code here