# how to activate and deactivate favorite icon in flutter

Tags: flutter, favorites

I want to activate and deactivate favorite icon for every individual item
as what I am getting now is to fill that icon but at the same time,it doesnt get
deactivated.

```
bool isPressed=false;
new GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() => isPressed = true);
                            },
                            child: Icon(Icons.favorite_sharp,
                                // color: Colors.redAccent,
                                color: (isPressed)
                                    ? Colors.red
                                    : Colors.black12)),
```

Now activation and deactivation is working but while selecting an individual favorite icon, it is showing all the favorite icon as selected.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: infoList.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    Info info = new Info(
      "${infoList[index].id}",
      "${infoList[index].name}",
      "${infoList[index].image}",
      "${infoList[index].thumb}",
      "${infoList[index].catagory}",
      "${infoList[index].price}",
      "${infoList[index].qty}",
    );
    return new Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5),
        elevation: 5,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        child: ClipRRect(
            child: ListTile(
                leading: Container(
                    child: Image.network("${infoList[index].image}")),
                title: Text(
                  "${infoList[index].name}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.black),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  "\$ ${infoList[index].price}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.black),
                ),
                trailing: Wrap(
                  spacing: 12,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() => isPressed = !isPressed);
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.favorite_sharp,
                            // color: Colors.redAccent,
                            color: (isPressed)
                                ? Colors.red
                                : Colors.black12)),

                    // Icon(
                    //   Icons.add_shopping_cart,
                    //   color: Colors.white,
                    // ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63496800/12789200

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just added an ' _ ' to the isPressed variable as it is a good practice to keep such variables as private.

i.e.

isPressed -> Public

_isPressed -> Private

```
bool _isPressed = false;
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
           setState(() => _isPressed = !_isPressed);
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.favorite_sharp,
                color: _isPressed ? Colors.red : Colors.black12)),
```

For each `widget` to have it's on selection you'll have to make it into a separate `Stateful Widget` and then pass it into the `ListView`.

Once you've done that now every `widget` will have it's own `state` and they can be separately selected / disselected.

**EDIT**

Make the `Card Widget` into another `StateFull widget`

For eg.

```
class CardWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final Info info;
  CardWidget(this.info);
  @override
  _CardWidgetState createState() => _CardWidgetState();
}

class _CardWidgetState extends State<CardWidget> {
  
bool _isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5),
            elevation: 5,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
            child: ClipRRect(
                child: ListTile(
                    leading: Container(
                        child: Image.network("${widget.info.image}")),
                    title: Text(
                      "${widget.info.name}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "\$ ${widget.info.price}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    trailing: Wrap(
                      spacing: 12,
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() => _isPressed = !_isPressed);
                            },
                            child: Icon(Icons.favorite_sharp,
                                // color: Colors.redAccent,
                                color: (isPressed)
                                    ? Colors.red
                                    : Colors.black12)),
    
                        // Icon(
                        //   Icons.add_shopping_cart,
                        //   color: Colors.white,
                        // ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Now use the `CardWidget` to populate the `ListView`.
Just remember to pass in all the values to the widget as shown below.

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: infoList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        Info info = new Info(
          "${infoList[index].id}",
          "${infoList[index].name}",
          "${infoList[index].image}",
          "${infoList[index].thumb}",
          "${infoList[index].catagory}",
          "${infoList[index].price}",
          "${infoList[index].qty}",
        );
        return CardWidget(info);
```

Comment: Thanks alot but here I can only select an item but cant deactivate it.

Comment: I edited the answer so now it supports select / disselect also added the logic for each widget to have it's own state. If this answers your query please select this as the Accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks alot but Where should i put Stateful widget as class is already under Stateful widget.Please see my editted question

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your onTap to actually toggle:

```
onTap: () {
  setState(() => isPressed = !isPressed);
},
```

Comment: Thanks alot but if I want to select only one favorite as while selecting single favorite icon,it has shown all the icons as a selected favorite items in a list view.

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#3