# Flutter: control multiple icons

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to let users choose an icon and they should only be able to choose one. The selected icon changes its color while all others stay unchanged. How can I do that?

Code:

```
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 25,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isPressed = !isPressed;
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(
                ESGIcons.star,
              ),
              color: (isPressed)
                  ? AppTheme.esgEasyYellow
                  : AppTheme.esgDarkBlue,
            ),
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 25,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isPressed = !isPressed;
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(
                ESGIcons.crown,
              ),
              color: (isPressed)
                  ? AppTheme.esgEasyYellow
                  : AppTheme.esgDarkBlue,
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63496800/12789200

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
List<Icon> icons = [
  ESGIcons.star,
  ESGIcons.crown,
];
int buttonOnPressed = -1;
ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection : Axis.horizontal,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: icons.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return IconButton(
        iconSize: 25,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            buttonOnPressed = index;
          });
        },
        icon: Icon(icons[index]),
        color: (buttonOnPressed == index)
            ? AppTheme.esgEasyYellow
            : AppTheme.esgDarkBlue,
      );
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. this worked with just one small edit: icon: Icon(icons[index]),
Do you know how to put the icons in a row instead of a column or list?

Comment: I update may answer, do you mean put it in horizontal way? You can try add         `scrollDirection : Axis.horizontal,`